# Distance between two airplanes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

I need help with a vector problem where my solution is different from that of my teacher. The translation of the problem reads as follows:

> An air traffic controller observes two aircraft on his radar screen. The first flies at an altitude of 865 m, at a **horizontal distance of 19.2 km**, and 25.0° south of west. The second spacecraft flies at an altitude of 1,150 m, at a **horizontal distance of 17.6 km**, and at 20.0° south of east.
> What is the distance between the two planes?

(This is my own translation, so I'm sorry if anything is wrong)

The way I solved is that I considered the given altitudes to be the z-coordinates of the airplanes, **the given horizontal distance to be the x-coordinates** and I used the tangent and the horizontal distance to get the y-coordinates. Therefore, the airplanes lie on the following points:

$(-19.2, -19.2 \tan 25^\circ, 0.865)$

$(17.6, -17.6 \tan 20^\circ, 1.15)$

I omitted the "km" units. Plotting such points in an xy plane, it looks like this:

[image: my solution]

At the end, I found the distance between the airplanes to be 36.9 kilometers.

However, the way they solved is different. They considered the data given as the "horizontal distance" as the distance between the origin and the aircraft, that is, the magnitude of a vector starting from the origin and ending in the airplanes. Their coordinates look like this:

$(-19.2 \cos25°, -19.2 \sin 25°, 0.865)$

$(17.6 \cos 20°, -17.6 \sin 20°, 1.15)$

This gives of course a different solution to the distance between the 2 aircraft, that is, 34.0 kilometers. I still don't get why they solved the problem like this. But before actually giving them my arguments about why I think the solution is different, I want to make sure I'm not the one who did things wrong.

Thank you so much for your help in advance and let me know if you need any more information! :)

Comment: You have the coordinates of the two planes.  Use the Pythogorean theorem in 3 dimensions to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was to assume that 'horizontal' meant a distance in the direction of an x-coordinate. Horizontal simply means normal to vertical- it does not imply any particular direction. Indeed, the question explicitly told you the directions in which the planes were flying, so you should have taken the 'horizontal' distance to mean the distance of the planes from the control tower in plan view.

Comment: So it turns out their answer was right. Thank you so much for reading my question and helping me. Now I realize I've understood the concepts "horizontal" and "vertical" wrong all my life.